# How to resize a TvView?

Tags: android, android-tv

My problem consist in displaying several input options as images. But when I use only one TvVIew, it convert all the screen. If I try to specific the size it doesnt display. Also, I have to create dynamically in code the TvView because if not, it doesnt work

Comment: Please share few code snippets and output of current code along with expectations to avoid delay in answers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question  actually. I was specifying the layer type as software by mistake. That was the reason of why it couldn't be resized.